# How to reset ngrx effects on logout ? NGRX Efftects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Tell me please how to reset all effects on some action (user logout)? 
Id like to reset all effects on LOG_OUT actions.
for exaple:

1. subscribe some effect on some action
2. trigger `takeUntil()` inside effect
3. logout
4. reset all effects
5. subscribe same effect on same action again (from step 1) .

at the moment step 5 doesnt work, cause `takeUntil()` unsubscribe that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added mergeMap and put takeUntil there. Now its nice.

```
 @Effect() createConversation$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(CREATE_CONVERSATION),
    map((action: CreateConversation) => action.payload),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectConversation))),
    mergeMap(([message, mdConversation]) => {
      return this.httpService
        .createConversation(mdConversation.data.taskId, message)
        .pipe(
          map(
            result =>
              new CreateConversationComplete({
                id: result.data.id,
                tmpId: mdConversation.data.id
              })
          ),
          catchError((error: MyError) => {
            if (error.type === MyerrorTypes.NETWORK) {
              return of(new CreateConversationRetry(message));
            }
            if (error.type === MyerrorTypes.APPLICATION) {
              return of(new CreateConversationError(mdConversation.data));
            }
          }),
          takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(LOG_OUT)))
        );
    })
  );


@Effect() createConversationRetry$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(CREATE_CONVERSATION_RETRY),
        mergeMap((action: CustomAction) =>
          of(action).pipe(
            delay(NETWORK_TIMEOUT),
            map(data => new CreateConversation(action.payload)),
            takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(LOG_OUT)))
          )
        )
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that takeUntil completes an observable: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/takeUntil.ts#L85
and you can't subscribe again. If you need to pause some effect after the user is logged out I would use kind of filtering:

```
withLatestFrom(..is logged in selector)
filter((isLoggedIn: boolean) => isLoggedIn)
```